# Error: 3190000 block_log_exception: Block log exception: block log does not contain last irreversible block

Tags: nodeos, error

I was getting an Error while  starting nodeos.

Error: 3190000 block_log_exception: Block log exception: block log does not contain last irreversible block

If you are getting the same error look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, go to your home directory.

Navigate to `~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos`

Here you will see two files `config` and `data`.

Delete the data folder using `rm -rf data/` and start your nodeos again. Error should be gone.

**OR**

You can use `--hard-replay` to replay the blockchain to the last irreversible block.

If you don't mind losing accounts that you have created, the first method is the best, however, if you do not want to lose the current accounts, make sure to use the second method.

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem